# passing arguments inside quote, e.g. screen -dm ' ls /home/$dir1 '

Tags: gnu-screen, arguments

I use the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Please enter the password of your XXXX:'
read -sp 'Password:' password
screen -dm bash -c '  BLABLA '
```

Problem is that my commands in BLABLA include the argument password (`$password`) and `$password` is not passed to inside the quotes `''`

I need the quotes so that I can execute a conditional statement in screen...
'`if ... then ...; fi`'

Best,
V

Comment: Passwords or any secret should never be passed on the command line, as the command line of processes is public within a given system. If you have a command that accepts passwords as arguments, it's broken by design.

Comment: Please don't post answers unless you are suggesting a novel solution to your question. If you need clarification on an existing answer, leave a comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

To properly pass `$password` as an argument into `bash -c`,

```bsh
screen -dm bash -c 'if [ "$1" = "somestring" ]; then echo ok; fi' bash "$password"
```

Things to note:

- The option-argument to the shell's `-c` option should be a single-quoted string.  If it is not, and you inject variables into it, you get a code injection vulnerability.
- The first non-option argument is the arbitrary string `bash`.  This will be the value given to `$0` inside the `bash -c` script and it will be used in any error messages generated by that shell.  It is customary to use the name of the shell for this string.
- The rest of the arguments will be placed in the list of positional argument, i.e., into `$1`, `$2` etc.  In this case, we pass a single argument, the quoted password string.  This ends up in `$1` inside the `bash -c` script.

Note Stéphane's comment on the question too, that passing passwords on the command line at all is inherently insecure.  This is since the arguments of commands are visible in the process list, and may under some circumstances be stored in audit logs and shell history files.  Credentials are sometimes stored on file with restrictive permissions, and could be read from there within the `bash -c` script.  Since I don't know *exactly* what you are wanting to do, I can't show any useful examples of that.

Note also that to properly read an arbitrary string, the `IFS` variable should have an empty string as value, or it will strip some whitespace characters from your input.  You also need `read -r` to allow proper input of backslash characters.

```bsh
IFS= read -s -p 'password: ' -r password
```

The initial `echo` that you use should, as it is a prompt to the user, write to the standard error stream,

```
echo 'Please enter the password of your XXXX:' >&2
```